# DataColumn of Type Double Accepting String Values

Tags: winforms, datatable, decimal, datacolumn

I was surprised that the solution to my problem of forcing to display a `Decimal` value with 2 decimal places on a `DataGridView` with data binded to a `DataTable` was:

```
DataRow newRow = this.MenuDataTable.NewRow();    
newRow["Price"] = menuItem.Price.ToString("0.00");
```

while the `Price` column itself was set to be of `Decimal` type (And the inserted object in the solution is a `string`). It was then that I noticed that the object `DataRow` accepts any `Object` type for obvious reasons that I initially hadn't thought.

My dilemma right now is "is it really safe to do that?". I actually validated the data first before inserting it to the `DataTable` which is as follows:

```
        if (!decimal.TryParse(this.Price, out outDecimal))
        {
            throw new InvalidUserValuesException("Price must be a number");
        }
        if (outDecimal < 0)
        {
            throw new InvalidUserValuesException("Price must be a positive number");
        }
        if (Decimal.Round(outDecimal, 2) != outDecimal)
        {
            throw new InvalidUserValuesException("Price must only have two decimal places");
        }
        if (this.Price.Length > 10)
        {
            throw new InvalidUserValuesException("Price must not exceed 10 characters");
        }
```

Believing that the answer is simple and straightforward, I just wanted to relieve myself of the fear for my application to blow up in the future.

Comment: "I was surprised that the solution to my problem of forcing to display 2 decimal places on data table ..." What problem are you talking about? There is no such thing as "display in data table". Display is presentation term, not data related.

Comment: You're right. I did miss some points in my explanation. I edited the question already. Thanks!